# How do I translate "Putting many ducks into space"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation

I'm trying to find how to say "Putting many ducks into space" in the most proper way, but I have very little experience in Latin and so the different forms of words are somewhat confusing to me. What would be the best way to translate that phrase?

The goal is myself, the speaker, to send them into space and by space I mean outside of our earth's atmosphere. The direct context is this; some person says "you know, no duck can go into space alone." To which I reply "I'm well aware, that is why my personal motto is '[Latin for "putting/sending many ducks into/to space"]'!"

Comment: Related (new question I just asked): https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10837/406

Comment: Welcome to the site! For the sake of future readers, I edited the context into the question and cleaned up some comments. (Comments are only meant to be temporary.) Feel free to edit any of your posts at any time to improve!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the context you've provided in the comments, I'd rephrase it a little bit:

> Anates [Multae] in Vacuum Jaciendae [Sunt]

This literally means "[Many] Ducks Must be Launched Into the Void". It's phrased more as a universal truth: yes, ducks must always be launched, it is a fact of life.

You can include *multae* or leave it out; it literally means "many". But imo including it weakens the statement in Latin. So personally, I'd leave it out. Similarly, *sunt* can be included or left out; it's pedantically correct, but I and all Latin-speakers I can think of would leave it off. Finally, *jaciendae* can be spelled with an *i* or with a *j* at the beginning; the meaning is exactly the same, so choose whichever looks better to you.

Luchonacho's translation is more like "[someone is] sending many ducks into the heavens". Also entirely correct, but it doesn't quite read as a motto.

Comment: Be assured that your score will incur no de-duck-tions.

Answer (score 0):

One option is

> Mittens multas anates in caelum

The tricky bit is "space" as in the place outside the atmosphere. I'm not sure there is a precise way to say it. Above, I use "sky". So the phrase would be "sending many ducks into the sky".

An alternative could be

> Mittens multas anates ultra atmosphaeram

This is, "sending many ducks beyond the atmoshpere".

PS [this discussion](http://latindiscussion.com/forum/latin/outer-space.22223/) might be on interest regarding "space".